# bootstrap two divs on each other (one used as background image)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Could you assist me with getting something like this done with bootstrap (or any other responsive css framework): [div on div example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av4b7.png)

I would like to have a container and then within a row 2 divs on top of each other, one div is background image (100% width) and another a top div with another image actually, I also want to apply animation to both divs, the background image needs to show up a little bit after the top div.

So far I was able to do something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row background-image">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 animation-1">
<img src="1.svg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I've used css to add the background image like this:

```
.background-image {background: black url("backgroundimage.svg") no-repeat;
                   background-position: center;
                   background-size:100% }
```

so that would work very nicely, but I "can't" add animation to my css class .background-image? so it would display just after the top div shows up

Comment: i dont understand, your image shows 3 boxes in a line, but you say you want `a container and then within a row 2 divs on top of each other`...can you explain this differently?

Comment: The image isn't that clear indeed, however the top div is one div and the background image div is a second div (it's full width of the row), no third div :). Perhaps this image will illustrate it better http://imgur.com/u3LFUPY The top div is in the center. Top div is centered by bootstrap offset 3

Comment: ok so your only issue is the animation you would like to add?

Comment: yes with this approach that is the only issue I believe. I don't know how could I add the animation (css fade in effect) to the background-image div. And otherwise if I don't use this approach I don't know how to use background-image div as the background under top div

Comment: That background image needs null alt text (i.e. alt=""). See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H67

Comment: adding alt will not change much here other than give the name a "name" as far as I know..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something really simple using jquery and `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){ //show image 1
  $(".background-img").animate({"opacity":"1"}); 
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){ //show image 2
  $(".background-top").animate({"opacity":"1"}); 
}, 1500);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eeuabzfn/)